# How many cups/tablespoons are in x% of a quart?

Tags: volume, unit-of-measure

I'm wanting to find an equation for calculating how many cups or tablespoons are in a certain percentage of a quart.

Example question to be solved with the equation: How many cups are in 10% of a quart?

I know there are four cups in a quart. A cup is 25% of a quart.

---

Thoughts after accepting an answer—

I got some good answers. I like the equation **`0.01xn`** (or x% of n), derived from some of those answers, where 0.01x is the percentage, and n is the number of units in the other kind of unit (e.g. the number of cups that can fit in a quart or the number of tablespoons that can fit in a gallon). So, if you want to know how many tablespoons are in 7% of a quart, you can do 0.01*7*64. (There are 64 tablespoons in a quart.) So, there are 4.48 tablespoons in 7% of a quart. **So, just convert the quart to tablespoons, cups, etc., and take the percentage of that.** Kind of obvious when you really think about it.

Anyway, in practice, this Q/A will be helpful for people wanting to lacto-ferment pickles/etc. with a certain percent salt solution (different people suggest a different percent); also, for people wanting to know how much sugar to add to make vinegar (I read that a 10% sugar solution is good); also, for people wanting to mix fertilizer in the right amounts—and so forth. Some fertilizers won't tell you how many tablespoons to add per quart, but they might tell you a percentage, or some other measure. Anyway, there are broad applications, so I figured I'd ask on the Math StackExchange site instead of Gardening/Landscaping or Cooking.

Comment: If there are $4$ cups in $1$ quart, then you have to divide $1$ by something to get $10%$. What is that something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 1 quart equals 64 tablespoons (which I [looked up](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how%20any%20table%20spoons%20in%20x%20quarts%3F) just to be sure), you have that the volume in tablespoons of $x\%$ of 1 quart equals $$64\cdot x\% = \frac{64x}{100} = \frac{16x}{25} = 0.64x$$

Comment: Yes. Also, $\%$ is literally a symbol that stands in for $\div100$, so $0.1=10\%$

Comment: I deleted my old comment right when you posted yours, because I realized before you replied that there was a percent on one x, but not the other (so, that answered my question: whether the 0.64x would amount to 6.4 if I wanted 10% of a quart, and it does; so, x is 10, and x% is 0.10). Thanks!

Comment: I did know that .1 is 10%, but I didn't know % could be used like that with both x and x% being used in the same problem. That's cool and makes the problem a lot shorter and easier to understand, I think, and it's insightful. So, although the first answer I accepted was great, and worked, I thought this would be easier for me to remember.

Comment: If you find that helpful, I highly recommend skimming the SI Brochure (that’s where I learned that, which also helped me immensely)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $4$ cups equals $100\%$ of a quart, then since they are proportional to each other, you have to divide both sides by $k$ so that the right-hand side is $10\%$.

Can you find what $k$ is?

Comment: Are you saying this is the equation? n/k=x% (solving for k) where n equals the number of units in a quart/gallon/etc? So if we have 256 tablespoons in a gallon, and want how many tablespoons is in 3% of a gallon, we could do 256/k=3%. 3%*256 = 7.68 tablespoons in 3% of a gallon (I know I didn't mention gallons in the question, but it doesn't seem to matter what unit it is as long as you know how many of the desired units are in it (n)).

Comment: So 0.01xn (or (xn)/100) might be a more concise equation derived from that. 0.01*3*256=7.68.

Answer (score 1):

First off, ditch the $\%$, if you can. They will distract you. $25\%$ of a quart means $0.25$ quarts, and $10\%$ of a quart means $0.1$ quarts.

You say in your post that
$$
1\text{ quart} = 4\text{ cup}
$$
is something you already know. Here is a great tip that, if you utilise it correctly, will help you in any converting problem you will ever face: Those units in the equation up there ($\text{quart}$ and $\text{cup}$), and any other unit, behaves algebraically just like a single letter. That means you can manipulate expressions that use those words the same way you can any $x$ or $a$ or $n$ you have ever come across. (Just be careful that if you stop midway through a calculation and try to *understand* what an intermediary expression says, it's not always easy.)

So, by manipulating our equation above, we get
$$
1 = 4\frac{\text{cup}}{\text{quart}}
$$
(Don't simplify away the $\text u$ here; it is the *entire word as one* that behaves like an algebraic letter and may be simplified if possible.) As you probably know, multiplying by $1$ doesn't change the value of anything. The last equation here says that $1$ and $4\frac{\text{cup}}{\text{quart}}$ are *exactly the same thing*. That means that multiplying by $4\frac{\text{cup}}{\text{quart}}$ doesn't change the value of anything.

Now you are ready to face your problem. You have $0.1\text{ quart}$. That is the same as $1\cdot 0.1\text{ quart}$. As per the above, this is the same as $4\frac{\text{cup}}{\text{quart}}\cdot 0.1\text{ quart}$. Here we can simplify: $\text{quart}$ disappears, and we're left with $4\text{ cup}\cdot 0.1 = 0.4\text{ cup}$.

So we have gone from $0.1\text{ quart}$ to $0.4\text{ cup}$ by only using operations that do not change the value of the expression (multiply by $1$, substitute one part for something which is equal, fraction simplification and finally carrying out the multiplication $4\cdot 0.1$ to get $0.4$). That means that the two must be equal, and we have our answer.

Now, this might seem like a lot of work, but if you do it like this, most of it will be in your head. The solution, as done here, but written on a test, might look something more like this:

> We have $$
> 1\text{ quart} = 4\text{ cup}\\
> 1 = 4\frac{\text{cup}}{\text{quart}}
> $$
>   Therefore
>   $$
> 0.1\text{ quart} = 4\frac{\text{cup}}{\text{quart}}\cdot 0.1\text{ quart}\\
> = 4\text{ cup}\cdot 0.1 = 0.4\text{ cup}
> $$